# How to install node mysql module in nw.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql, nw.js

I am building a desktop application in NW.JS. Now, I want to store data in database using MySQL but I don't know how to add MySQL node module in my nw.js application. Kindly answer it in detail i am beginner. I added `require('mysql');` but it says `no mysql module exist`

```
<script>
var sql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'locahost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'db_delvin'
});
 <script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line (terminal) run the following command in the root folder of your project:

```
npm install mysql --save
```

*the `--save` appendix will save the dependency in the `package.json` of your application*

Every time you see a `require` or `import` in Javascript it means that a module is necessary to be loaded to charge dependency's functionalities. **NW.js** is a module loader for the DOM but it still requires the modules you want to use in your application to be installed.

Check the `package.json` in the root of your application folder to see other required dependencies.